# Passing JSON to WEB API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this model for an MVC WEB API controller.
What will be the corresponding JSON to match this model structure?

```
namespace CarEvaluator.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Record
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Boolean> CHits { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Boolean> MHits { get; set; }
    }
}




public void Post(Record record)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure:

```
{"CHits":[true,false],"MHits":[true,false]}
```

Example:

```
var postObject = new Object();

// Initialize CHits and MHits as arrays
postObject.CHits = [];
postObject.MHits = [];

// push some items into the arrays
postObject.CHits.push(true);
postObject.CHits.push(false);
postObject.MHits.push(true);
postObject.MHits.push(false);

// serialize data to post
// this is what you set as data property in for instance jquery ajax
$.ajax({
    //other params, content type etc
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postObject),
    ...
    });
```

if your parameter is null, you should try to add the [FromBody] attribute and decorate the method with httppost

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Record record)
{

}
```

Comment: I am using this JSON {"CHits":[true,false],"MHits":[true,false]} in fiddler composer, and the controller does not get the data, shows NULL. Any idea?

Comment: OK, I forgot to pass the content negotiation stuff for the JSON. After adding the HTTP headers: 
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
All works OK